# javascript entire page fly in and out effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Recently I came across a site that had an interesting effect, I can't remember which site it was. The effect is that on navigation click, the entire current page fly away to the top-right corner and disappear, and the new page flys in from the bottom-left and occupy the browser window.

Does anyone know where I can obtain a example code of this effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/)

Instead of divs you can do this for your whole page (**body element**).
First you have to define a class for all links () tags. When the user clicks any link you can call the effect for the whole page.(i.e first on the current page and then when the new page loads you again call the effect)

Answer (score 0):

that's called single/one page theme. see this demo:

- http://themeforest.net/item/stratum-html-single-page-template/full_screen_preview/1668778
- http://themeforest.net/item/volemo-html-one-page-template/full_screen_preview/1359429

try jquery `.scroll()`

the key concept is you create a single large page (eg. height: 2500px) then assign anchor-link scroll to fix position.

Comment: thanks but that's not quite the effect I saw. The effect I saw was not a single large page preloaded, and also the entire page flew away, not just part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive Similar effect on normal site by doing the following to the main body tag

- add a click event on the navigation links which uses jQuery effects to slide your page out fast
- add an onload(`$(document).ready();`) event to all the pages which slides in the body as you want